# Shifted convolution problem for Coefficients of automorphic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, convolution

The shifted convolution problem for coefficients of modular forms is well studied and many estimates were established for the shifted convolution sums of Hecke eigenvalues. So, one may ask about the generalization of these estimates to the case of automorphic forms: Are there analogue estimates for the shifted convolution sums of automorphic forms? 
Thank you.

Comment: The following brand new paper is relevant: http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.07644